# Can these two jQuery functions be combined into one that is more efficient?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two functions in jQuery to hide and then show a header, and also swap the buttons out so that when the header is hidden, the "show header" button appears, and vice versa.  They are as follows:

```
$('#close_header').click(function() {
    $('#header').animate({ top: '-=150px' }, 500);
    $(this).toggle();
    $('#open_header').toggle();
});

$('#open_header').click(function() {
    $('#header').animate({ top: '+=150px' }, 500);
    $(this).toggle();
    $('#close_header').toggle();
});
```

The markup to go along with is as follows:

```
<img src="images/close.png" id="close_header" class="header_control fadein button">
<img src="images/open.png" id="open_header" class="header_control fadein button">
<div id="header">
    *Header content.*
</div>
```

Is there any way to combine those two functions into one for neatness and efficiencies' sake?

Comment: combining these functions is not more neat, and the efficiency is negligible.  You will end up violating single responsibility for each of these functions, which is no good.

Comment: This is js, sometimes brevity trumps single resposibility

Comment: agree with @Woot4Moo additionally changing the `toggle()` for `show()` / `hide()` as appropriate would be more explicit.

Comment: @Maess i have this feeling that you may not work on "enterprise" level applications or write APIs that are distributed to large user bases.

Comment: @NaOH Define more efficient. Easier to maintain, easier to read, or quicker to execute. Only two of those matter in this case.

Comment: Sorry Woot not everyone shares your opinions...

Comment: @Maess correct that is why they are opinions, the thing is I generally back mine up with research from sources such as IEEE and ACM.  This of course does not always apply and it is still an opinion irrespective of how informed it is.

Comment: Man NaOH, look at the storm you've caused!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no performance difference.

If you try to write it all in one function with parameters it will only be less readable.

Keep it that way, it's fine.

Now answering your question:

> Is there any way to combine those two functions...

**Yes**

> Is there any way to combine those two functions into one for neatness and efficiencies' sake?

**No.** Read the codes in the other answers, are they neater? are they more efficient? **NO**

Comment: +1 I prefer "DRY", but in this case even I would leave them separate. Now, if there were *many* such functions ..

Comment: @pst. If there were _many_ such functions you will still had to have lots of "if"s so... I would even then separate the functions.

Comment: @gdoron If there were *many* (read: more than ~2) such function pairs I would [likely] write a meta-function as that would get on my "copy'n'paste" radar .. but it's a different use-case, and I agree with this answer here.

Comment: @Woot4Moo. I liked that! It's funny that almost every time that I meet a guy asking me about such "performance boosts" at work, I see a lot more critical slow code they use...

Comment: usually how it works, and i have been guilty of converting things into O(n!) but i realize the error of my ways

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only have those two `.header_control`s:

```
$('.header_control').click(function() {
    var dist = (this.id=="open_header") ? '+=150px' : '-=150px';
    $('#header').animate({top: dist}, 500);
    $('.header_control').toggle(); // both at once
});​
```

It's hard to know from your code sample, but you might even be able to replace that `.animate(...)` method with a simple [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

```
$('.header_control').click(function() {
    $('#header').slideToggle(500);
    $('.header_control').toggle(); // both at once
});​
```

Comment: the same question I posed to everyone else, how does this make debugging any easier?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Because of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#open_header, #close_header').on('click', function(e) {
    var q = this.id=='open_header';
    $('#header').animate({ top: q?'+':'-'+'=150px' }, 500);
    $(this).toggle();
    $('#'+(q?'close':'open')+'_header').toggle();
});
```

Comment: and this makes debugging easier how?

Comment: @Woot4Moo The "150px" is only in one place, for starters.

Comment: the $(this).toggle() and $("#close_header").toggle() should be changed to $(".header_control").toggle() to tag both controls at 1x. If you always run $("#close_header") you will run into issues when it is the close_header triggering the click.

Comment: @Blazemonger and once again, this makes debugging easier how?  We removed a line of code, but if something in the function breaks later on, how can we easily debug open vice close?

Comment: --`$(this).toggle();$('#close_header').toggle();` ++`$('#open_header, #close_header').toggle()`

Comment: Adding a class to both `#open_header` and `#close_header` would help things.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Nobody's asking you to debug it. Feel free to submit your own answer.

Comment: @woot - The ternary might be the only slightly confusing thing to beginners, but they're no mystery to any slightly experienced programmer. I read that out with no confusion so debugging would be no problem. I do agree with your initial statement though. I don't see why it would matter to combine the two.

Comment: $("#"+this.id) is still wrong because it just retoggles what you toggled in $(this).toggle()

Comment: @Blazemonger If the OP uses the above solution, someone will have to debug it.

Comment: With your newest edit you are doing the same check twice for no reason!

Comment: @KaiQing A bit insulting, but whatever.  Code is to be written for humans to maintain not computers.

Comment: It's like hand-obfuscation .. even if it were working (I have not taken time to validate), I do not approve of such a "clever" approach.

Comment: I believe the question was "Is there any way to combine those two functions into one", and the answer is probably "yes", not "don't do it" ?

Comment: @woot - oh I know. I tend to not care about slight performance issues cause almost nobody in the general web dev world builds real enterprise level websites that serve to millions by the minute. You'll notice I did not defend the answer though. It needs debugging but it wouldn't be hard to push things around to get it right, even if your purpose for doing so is just to know if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#close_header, #open_header').click(function() {
    var isClose = this.id == 'close_header';
    var minPlus = isClose ? '-' : '+';
    $('#header').animate({ top: minPlus + '=150px' }, 500);
    $(this).toggle();
    $('#' + isClose ? 'open_header': 'close_header').toggle();
});
```

Comment: someone doesn't like ternary operators =p

Comment: @gdoron At least it's not adeneo's answer :-)

Comment: @pst hehe well now that answer looks the same as mine with all the edits that happened lol.

Comment: @Woot4Moo. I'm fine with ternary operators when they are need. But when you use them cuz you can... For what benefit? Write all the code in one function. WOW!

Comment: @gdoron help the compiler! /sarcasm